# Trying to get a Windows Service to run an executable on a shared drive

Tags: executable, unc, windows-share

I have c# that will run in a windows service.  I'm trying to use the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes to run an executable.  If the executable is on the local drive, no problem.  However, I need to run an executable on a shared drive.  I've tried using the UNC notation (//machine_name/share_name/directory/runme.exe), but the process seems to hang.  The service and shared drive are on Windows XP.  Has anyone tackled this issue before?

Comment: Just to clarify your UNC notation...do you really  mean "//machine_name/share_name/directory/runme.exe" or "\\machine_name\share_name\directory\runme.exe" ?

Comment: should be \'s   you can tell my preferred environment.... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account your service is running as likely does not have permission to access the shared drive.  Try configuring it to run as a user with permission to the network via the services applet.  Right click on the service, choose properties and set the account in the login tab.

Answer (score 1):

What account is the service running as?

LocalSystem will only allow access to the local file system. If you want to access a network resource, you will have to run the service as a domain or network user.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=471168&SiteID=1

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

If the app on the shared drive is a .Net app, make sure it has sufficient trust.